# Android rendering doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

When starting  new project in android studio i get a rendering error on my main_activity page when i'm on the design view.

the error i get is:

Rendering Problems The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
- PorterDuff Color Filters are not supported.

The code is just the basic beginning code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

changing the device monitor to another version doesn't work.
how can i solve this?

Comment: Try to rebuild your project. Build -> ReBuild Project

Comment: Tried doing that but still the same error

Comment: It may be because of the recent updates in support library you have added to your gradle. you can ignore it and try to run, if it is not working, then think about it.

Comment: now i get this error:
 Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.LayoutlibCallback.getXmlFileParser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser; (Details)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1 ) **Build** - > **Rebuild Project**

2 ) **Tools** -> **Android** -> **Sync Project with gradle files**

3) **Refresh your layout view**